# AngularJS and Javascript Class :: ERROR ReferenceError: <oblect > is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, editorjs

I am trying to use custom Java Script class in AngularJS [v 10] typescript object. But not able to use the same and getting error as

> ERROR ReferenceError:  is not defined

Here is my code

**JavaScript** simple-image.js file

```
export class SimpleImage {

    constructor() {
    }
    
    render(){
        return document.createElement('input');
    }
}
```

Register the file in angular.json

```
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/simple-image.js"
            ]
```

Use the JavaScript file in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import EditorJs from '@editorjs/editorjs';
import Header from '@editorjs/header';

declare var SimpleImage:any; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  
  title = 'editor-example';
  public editor: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.editor = new EditorJs({

      holderId: "contentpart",
      autofocus: true,
      tools: {
        header: {
          class: Header,
          inlineToolbar: ['link'],
          config: {
            placeholder: 'Header'
          }
        },
        image: {
          class: new SimpleImage(),
          inlineToolbar: ['link'],
        } 
      },

      /**
      * onReady callback
      */
      onReady: () => {
        alert('Editor.js is ready to work!')
      }
    }),

    this.editor.isReady
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Editor.js is ready to work!')
        /** Do anything you need after editor initialization */
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        console.log(`Editor.js initialization failed because of ${reason}`)
      });
    }

}
```

And I am getting following error in console

```
ERROR ReferenceError: SimpleImage is not defined
ngOnInit app.component.ts:38
Angular 24
```

Comment: `SimpleImage` is not imported

Comment: Added "import SimpleImage from '../assets/js/simple-image.js';" but still getting same error

Comment: remove this line too `declare var SimpleImage:any; 
`

Comment: On removal .. getting following error ------ ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts 24:27-38
"export 'default' (imported as 'SimpleImage') was not found in '../assets/js/simple-image.js'

Comment: With adding of "import * as SimpleImage from '../assets/js/simple-image';" it is compiled now .. but now it is giving following error ..ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: t is undefined
value@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:45882:1 .. But if i simple remove the use of  image: {
          class: new SimpleImage(),
          inlineToolbar: ['link'],
        }                                                                                                                    It is not showing the error any more. Then how to implement SimpleImage.